# How to set Gujarati joint word in Android?

Tags: android, fonts, typeface

I have created an android app, in that I want to set Gujarati joint word.

I use **Shruti.ttf** font.

I want to print -

**નર્સિંગ**

But it prints-

નર્ સંગિ

So, how to print proper.

My code is -

```
TextView tv_guj=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_gujarati);
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Shruti.ttf");
tv_guj.setTypeface(font);
tv_guj.setText("નર્સિંગ");
```

Comment: Whats the reason for -1 ?

Comment: have you tried any other fonts ?

Comment: Sorry @Kedarnath, I don't understand your question.

Comment: Yup, I also try Lohit-Gujarati.ttf. But result is same

Comment: some gujarati fonts doesnt display gujarati character properly. So I request you to try any other gujarati font.

Comment: does it shows same results with Lohit ?

Comment: Yes....result is same

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51793/discussion-between-sweta-sharma-and-kedarnath)

Comment: Hello @Sweta...Is it compalsary to use Shruti fonts ?

Comment: @SwetaSharma is this trick working or not?? I need same thing, so please let me know.

Comment: @SwetaSharma is this was worked for you then please let me know, I am newbie in android a and need almost same thing like you did in this.

Comment: @SwetaSharma I really need this and I cant found this on google, please let me know. Its urgent for me.

Comment: @SwetaSharma hellow, please help me

Comment: @SwetaSharma can you please provide me your sample of code please?

Comment: @swetaSharma hey, can you please provide me the code???? I am waiting for it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use terafont of gujarati Fontface so it will be implemented.

Thanks

Comment: which terafont ? I have tried TERAFONT- CHANDAN  But it's not working proper in ICS. But Lohit_Gujarati And SHRUTI works fine with jelly bean and KITKAT. Give me suggestion for best terafont name.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this sample and copy your text to this sample text view it will work and will show proper result as you want

https://www.dropbox.com/s/6pqg9otcli038ij/HindiFont.zip

Lohit-Gujarati font is working

Comment: Nopes, even with Lohit, it results same, I double checked it.

Comment: @Kedarnath have you checked this sample i have checked in my device and showing perfect

Comment: Yes, I said I double checked it. I tried your example, it is working fine, but when I used your font with Sweta's code it is giving same result.

Comment: @Kedarnath which android os version are you testing app ?